# Ellipsis issue with va_start() on nRF52840

Tags: c, ellipsis, nrf52

I want to retreive my args from an ellipsis using va_start.

Here is my code :

```
char str[256];
void nrf_log_flash(bool is_to_save, char * log, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, log);
    int ret = vsprintf(str, log, args);
    if(is_to_save){
         sprintf(str, "%s : %s\n", nrf_cal_get_time_string(false), log);
         //my_nrf_log_add(str, strlen(str));
    }
    NRF_LOG_INFO("%s", log);
    NRF_LOG_INFO("%s", str);
    NRF_LOG_INFO("%d", ret);
    va_end(args);

}
```

And here is my calling :

```
nrf_log_flash(true, "button %d pressed, %u, %x, %c", 2, 3658, 0xca, 'a');
```

But my va_list is empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by and how do you check that "your va_list is empty" ?

Comment: This code sample is incomplete. Please check a simple printf of str directly after vsprintf to verify the error is not in the code after.

Comment: if `is_to_save` is true then you immediately overwrite what you just printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
int ret = vsprintf(str, log, args);
```

your str variable contains the formatted string (e.g. str is "button 2 pressed, 3658, ca, a". however, you next sentence overwrite this data. as you call sprintf, and overwrite the data at str with the 'log' variable which is the format ("button %d pressed, %u, %x, %c")

```
if(is_to_save){
     //THIS CODE OVERWRITE YOUR STR BUFFER
     sprintf(str, "%s : %s\n", nrf_cal_get_time_string(false), log);
     //my_nrf_log_add(str, strlen(str));
}
```

BTW, it is recommended to use snprint, and vsnprintf to avoid buffer overflow. as the format contains '%s', it may be printed with a large string which is larger than 256 bytes.

Comment: it works perfectly, but I don't understand why my str is overwrited, when I call vsprintf the tag are replaced by the arguments and stored into str right ? So when I call sprintf in the next line how can it put back the tags into str ?

Comment: @Firerazzer When you call `sprintf` the substituted values are in `str` and `log` is now finished with. I'm guessing you need something like `sprintf( datedStr, "%s : %s\n", nrf...(), str);` to create a _new_ string (`datedStr`) containing a time-stamp and `str` (the contents of `log` with substituted values). You should also be aware that you will have problems if any of these messages get too long (around 256 characters).

Comment: @TripeHound Ho yes... it's so obvious now... Thanks you for your time and patience ! Yes I replaced sprintf() by snprintf() and vsprintf() by vsnprintf(), thx for the tips